# How to read post data in Express.js

Tags: node.js, post, express, body-parser

I am trying to read post data in Express.js , with using body-parser middleware. But getting follwing error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
at /var/www/html/forkom/routes/index.js:49:28
at callbacks (/var/www/html/forkom/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
at param (/var/www/html/forkom/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
```

My code is something like

```
  var express = require('express'), routes = require('./routes');
  var app = express.createServer();
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var multer = require('multer'); 
  require('./routes/index')(app); // use route
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data
});
```

And I am using it with following route:

```
    app.post('/addComment', function (req, res) {
       var text   =  req.body.text; // error on this line
       res.json({"done":"yes",text:text});

     });
```

I have tried bothy with ajax call :

```
$("#postComment").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"/addComment",
                data:{text:$('.text-comment').val()},
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

and also using postman App.

Comment: How do you post the data?

Comment: Do you run this in `production` mode? As you configure this only in production. Moreover, try to put `app.use(app.router);` after `app.use(multer());`

Answer (score 0):

Try change .use middleware order, example:

```
  app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data
  app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

If not help try without multer, if after this you can get your json body say me.

```
app.use(multer({inMemory: true, onParseEnd: function(req, next){
    for(var file in req.files){
        if (file != 'archive'){
            req.body = JSON.parse(req.files[file].buffer);
        }
    }
    return next();
}}));
```

Ok. Try this, if you will have json body say me.

Ok, so lets try this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:1024*1024, verify: function(req, res, buf){
    try {
        JSON.parse(buf);
    } catch(e) {
        res.send("bad json");
    }
}}));
```

Comment: ok, try stringify your body before send in ajax

JSON.stringify(data:{text:$('.text-comment').val()});